# Create an auxiliary function in R for a matrix:

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following matrix:

[image: Picture of matrix]

The column & row names are city names, and each point of the matrix is the distance (in miles) between the two cities. For example, if my point is [SanFrancisco, Berkeley] the distance is 13.9. I am trying to figure out a function that given a vector of cities, and the matrix of distances between cities, the function returns the total distance between the provided cities. I don't really know where to start.

EDIT: If there are multiple cities involved (Berkeley -> SanFrancisco->PaloAlto, etc), I figure you have to use some sort of loop? Would it be a repeated loop?

Comment: Can you add the result from `dput(matrix)` and remove the picture.  Also give us the vector of city names and what you would like as the result.  We can't load data from a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is your matrix:

```
matrix <- structure(c(0, 3, 5, 3.6, 0, 2.1, 6, 1.9, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L
), .Dimnames = list(c("Vienna", "Berlin", "Prague"), c("Vienna", "Berlin", "Prague")))

           Vienna Berlin Prague
Vienna      0    3.6    6.0
Berlin      3    0.0    1.9
Prague      5    2.1    0.0
```

**you can do the following with basic subsetting:**

```
matrix["Vienna","Berlin"]
```

and you will get

```
[1] 3.6
```

**However if you want a custom function, you could do:**

```
    #define function
    getDist <- function(cityVector, matrix) {

      dist <- 0
      n    <- length(cityVector) - 1

      for(i in 1:n)  {
          dist <- dist + matrix[cityVector[i], cityVector[i+1]]
      }

      return(dist)
   }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to find the distance if there were multiple cities? For example, Berkeley to Oakland to SF? Would I use a repeat loop?